# HeadlessChrome GitLab CI

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci, karma-runner

The excat error code I recieve from GitLab looks like this:

```
$ npm run test -- --no-watch --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI
> frontend@0.0.0 test
> ng test --no-watch --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
27 05 2023 08:46:10.790:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
27 05 2023 08:46:10.793:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessCI with concurrency unlimited
27 05 2023 08:46:10.795:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot load browser "ChromeHeadlessCI": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
27 05 2023 08:46:10.795:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: Found 1 load error
    at Server.<anonymous> (/builds/live-stream-editor-zur-korrektur-von-untertiteln/frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:243:26)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Server.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Server.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitListeningNT (node:net:1774:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

It seams like i would miss some plugin but in the Karma.config.js which contains this:

```
autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', "ChromeHeadless", "ChromeHeadlessCI"],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    }
```

Currently i am clueless whats the problem, for me it seems like i have the right code set up.

Comment: Maybe you need to install [karma-chrome-launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-chrome-launcher) in the CI job, before you run the tests.